# correct use of requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to set up requirejs on my website, I have HTML modules and only want to load the JS when the particular HTML module is used.

I have these files and code, it works fine I just want to make sure I'm doing it correctly. The example below is for the implementation of a slider with the slick plugin. The php I include in index.php holds the relevant HTML for the slider.

**scripts/modules/Sliderbanner.js**

```
define(function(require) {
    var $ = require('jquery');
    var domReady = require('domready');

require('plugins/slick.min');
    domReady(function() {                  

            ///SLIDER BANNER
           $('.slider-banner').slick(});

        });
});
```

**scripts/page/sliderbanner.js**

```
  require(['main'], function() {
        require(['jquery', 'modules/Sliderbanner'], function($) {

        });
    });
```

**scripts/main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '../scripts',
    paths: {
        jquery:            'components/jquery/jquery',
        domready:          'components/requirejs-domready/domReady'
    },
    shim: {
        'slick.min': ['jquery']
    },
    urlArgs: "bust=" +  (new Date()).getTime()
});
define(function(require) {
    var $        = require('jquery');
    var domReady = require('domready');

    domReady(function() {

    });
});
```

**index.php**

```
 <?php include("../organisms/slider-banner.php");?>
      <script>require(['page/sliderbanner']);</script>
```

Does this look more or less correct to you? One doubt I do have is if I'm not really passing anything to the  scripts/page/sliderbanner.js from the module, do I really need it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your example would work if you bundle all with [`r.js`](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).

If you want to load asynchronously your JS files, then you need to do it like this:

```
// module.js

define(['/path/to/module1.js', 'path/to/module2.js', function (module1, module2) {
  // ...
});

// some-other-module.js

define(['/path/to/module.js'], function (module) {
  // ...
});
```